# Why is the second element being printed as 1?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int arr[4]={0,0,0,0};
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++){
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
 }
}
```

The following C code prints the second element , i.e. arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoPfZ.png) as 1. It should print 0. The rest of the elements are being printed as 0.

[image]

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Your results cannot be reproduced. Are you sure this is all there is to it?

Comment: Are you sure? in my case, there is no one.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you positive that its just you and a buggy compiler? gcc v4.9.3 does not produce what you're claiming is the issue.

Comment: compiler version is gcc 4.6.3

Comment: Try a newer version of compiler, re-compile the source and re-run it again and see the results.

Comment: @t0mm13b I doubt even an old version of gcc would botch compiling code this simple.

Comment: The code you posted is good and runs fine.Try delete your makefile if any, object file and executable and compile and link again. You could be running an older version of your code.

Comment: Also do `cat example_1_sizeof.c`

Comment: From what I recalled, gcc 4.6.3 had issues, but now that is a linaro build on 64bit platform, I'd rather chalk this down as a compiler bug that has been long resolved.

Comment: Thanks. Will try with a different version of gcc.

Comment: Voting to close as the issue is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a screenshot and configuration settings of your compiler as we cannot replicate the issue. It seems to work perfectly.

[I compiled your code in here, and you can see the result](http://ideone.com/ncViR7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int arr[4]={0,0,0,0};
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++){
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
 }
```

}